# dcc32 -JL filename.dpk results with fatal error the unit 'Classes' not found?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I have a Delphi package that I need to build using C++Builder, so I tried:

```
dcc32 -JL filename.dpk
Embarcadero Delphi for Win32 compiler version 35.0
Copyright (c) 1983,2022 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
filename.inc(xxx)
filename.pas(xx) Fatal: F2613 Unit 'Classes' not found.
```

The `dcc32.cfg` has:

```
-aWinTypes=Windows;WinProcs=Windows;DbiProcs=BDE;DbiTypes=BDE;DbiErrs=BDE
-u"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\win32\release"
```

Where is this `Classes` unit found, or should it be omitted? In other words, why won't it compile or find `Classes`?

Comment: The correct unit name is `System.Classes`. If you are trying to compile an old package in a modern compiler version, you will have to either 1) update the project to enable use of [`Unit Scope Names`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Unit_Scope_Names) (in this case, `System`), or else 2) update all of the project's `uses` clauses to include the Unit Scope Names (ie, change `Classes` to `System.Classes`, etc).

Comment: @RemyLebeau How do you update the project to enable use of the scope name rather than update all of the .pas files?  I didn't see anything at that link

Comment: The linked page links to the [Delphi Compiler](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Delphi_Compiler) page, which includes the `Unit Scope Names` option. The option is not stored in the `.dpk` itself, though. It would be in an associated `.dproj` instead (which C++Builder doesn't use, it uses `.cbproj` instead). You should be able to specify the `Unit Scope Names` option in the `.cfg` file via the `-NS` switch, eg: `-NSSystem;Vcl;...`, etc